# searching for installed drivers: all properties are empty

Tags: c#, driver, wmi-query

I want to get all a list of all installed drivers on my machine. For this purpose I use WMI. But for unknown reason all properties returned have empty values (except for deviceID, DriverVersion and Signer) .

What I tried and considered so far:

running with and without admin rights makes no difference

no methods found like fetch, load, reload on any of involved objects found

no option found like lazyload

pnputil.exe and driversearch.exe do return data of all drivers, but the outputs of those a very hard to interpret

This is the C#-code:

```
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver"))
        {
            foreach (ManagementBaseObject u in searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach(PropertyData prop in u.Properties)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}={prop.Value}");
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine("===");
            }
        }
```

Output for first driver found:

```
Caption=
ClassGuid=
CompatID=
CreationClassName=
Description=
DeviceClass=
DeviceID=\\SVWPSW46\P3115 X WC 7120-D C S U A3
DeviceName=
DevLoader=
DriverDate=
DriverName=
DriverProviderName=
DriverVersion=2:6.0,2:5.2,2:5.1,2:5.0
FriendlyName=
HardWareID=
InfName=
InstallDate=
IsSigned=True
Location=
Manufacturer=
Name=
PDO=
Signer=Microsoft Windows
Started=
StartMode=
Status=
SystemCreationClassName=
SystemName=
===
...
```

Comment: That is pretty normal.  It is [up to the driver writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547139(v=vs.85).aspx) to provide this data.  They just don't, nothing you can do about it.